# ipfw (Dummynet) cannot configure queue size for pipe

Tags: linux, queue, pipe, ipfw

I'm trying to use Dummynet (ipfw pipe) for simulating network switch.

My platform is Linux **CentOS 6.4 Final**

I have downloaded and compiled the latest version of source code (20130607) from [here](http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/dummynet/).

I'm trying to add pipe for relaying ip traffic between two subnets, and everything works fine. But as I try to set the queue size for pipe it fails.

Here is my command:

```
sudo ipfw pipe 1 config delay 64ms plr 0 bw 1000Mbit/s queue 100Kbytes
```

Here is the output:

```
ipfw: queue size must be < 4B
```

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

On FreeBSD where dummynet is built-into the kernel the maximum queue sizes are configurable via sysctl.

For example, to read the maximum queue sizes settings (in slots and bytes):

```
sysctl net.inet.ip.dummynet.pipe_slot_limit
sysctl net.inet.ip.dummynet.pipe_byte_limit
```

to set maximum queue sizes:

```
#these are the defaults on freebsd
sysctl net.inet.ip.dummynet.pipe_slot_limit=100
sysctl net.inet.ip.dummynet.pipe_byte_limit=1048576
```

While you use CentOS these might not apply directly (and I have never used it on other OS than FreeBSD), but I am pretty sure you need to find where to configure the max queue sizes for dummynet, because the error you get is displayed when you try to set a higher value that is allowed by the settings.

Comment: Thanks for your description, I'm now looking into the Linux implementation to see if it supports these settings as well or not.